# Retaging Folder as Album

Tags: folder-redirection

I have a bunch of audio files in a folder labeled, say, Frank Sinatra, and in most programs this will show up as a folder but not an album.  How do I tag it so it show up as an "album?'

Comment: did you get these audio files from online or ripped from CD? audio files come with something called "metadata" which tell the computer the artist, release date, album, etc. I'm willing to bet you downloaded these songs from the internet. Download audacity, open the file and then under file click edit metadata. If its blank try filling it in and see if that does it.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually these are files I copied into folders from my vinyl collection so they were in albums but the folders don't show up as albums

Comment: Thanks again.  This worked fine.  I had to use import and export multiple to handle the large number of files.

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the given seeing as it does indeed describe the nessisary steps to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to set metadata.

The tool I favour for this is [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) - make sure the tags are set correctly. MP3tag has a few advanced features that makes this easier (wildcards for tag -> filename and filename to tag) - but essentially, drag in all your music, and fix up the tags.

So, lets assume I have all my music in a predictable layout.

[image]

As mp3tag understands it, its something like `f:\musicsort\%artist%\%album%\%_codec%\%title%2` - so I can just feed that into convert filename to tag to convert it, or manually select tracks to update. This needs some finessing for your *exact* path - but in this case

[image]

This will pull the artist name, album name and title from the file system structure - leaving out the 2 I've somehow added into every track by accident.